# Is it possible to select a java.awt.Frame with Robot Framework in conjunction with SwingLibrary?

Tags: java, swing, robotframework, gui-testing

I've been testing a Java Swing based application with Robot Framework in conjunction with Swing Library for some time. I'm stuck in one of the test cases because the `Select Window` keyword does not find the desired window on the screen, although it is visible.

Here's a code snippet showing the relevant keywords of this test case:

```
...
Select Window      Main Window
Push Button        Add Person
List Windows
Select Window      Person Manager
```

The first three lines are working fine, but the `Select Window Person Manager` fails with the following rather short message:

```
14:24:40    FAIL    Frame with name or title 'Person Manager'
```

After debugging the application under test I identified the source of the problem: the window not being found is instance of `java.awt.Frame`.

Interestingly, it is listed by `List Windows`.

Is there a known workaround or existing extension of Swing Library to be able to focus on a `java.awt.Frame`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem by adapting the existing source code of Swing Library.
It can be easily downloaded from github (https://github.com/robotframework/SwingLibrary).
There are three classes which need to be changed to additionally allow windows of type `java.awt.Frame`.

First, there is the class `org.robotframework.swing.window.FrameOperator`. Instead of extending `JFrameOperator` it has to extend `FrameOperator`.
So, the adapted version of this class looks as follows:

```
 public class FrameOperator extends org.netbeans.jemmy.operators.FrameOperator ... {
    ...
    private static ComponentChooser createRegExpChooser(String title) {
          //change from JFrameFinder to FrameFinder
          return new FrameFinder(...);
    }

 }
```

Additionally, the method `private boolean titleMatches` in class `org.robotframework.swing.chooser.ByNameOrTitleFrameChooser` needs to be adapted to also support components that are an instance of `java.awt.Frame`.

Finally, line 89 in class `org.robotframework.swing.keyword.window.WindowKeywords` needs to be removed.

The new version of Swing Library can easily be built using `mvn package`.